# How to change UIAlertView Backgroung color or background image in ios7?

Tags: ios7

I want to customize the `UIAlertView` background color in iOS7.
can any one give the correct solution for this?
 the followings are my code.

```
void UIAlertViewQuick(NSString* title, NSString* message, NSString* dismissButtonTitle) {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:dismissButtonTitle
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil
                          ];


    [alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can't custom view of `UIAlertView`.
You can choose [this](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) solution in iOS7 and later.

Answer (score 0):

- No, you can't customise a UIAlertView.
- So if you have to do it, you can do it using a UIView that gives a UIAlertView-like display. You can create a custom view with buttons and use it throughout the app.
- you may check this [link](https://github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView). It might help you!

Comment: Hi raja, thank you for your response.we can add a UIView to UIAlertView accessory to perform this action as you mentioned above link, no need to go third parties.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot change the entire UIAlertview background color, we can change the inputView color only using the following code

alert.inputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

if you need to change entire alert view color means you can add custom alert view.
Thank you.